# How do i set width for the codebox (PrismJS)

Tags: html, css, prismjs

So i am basically trying to set width for the codebox (i am using prismJS), when i add too big of a code it breaks everything and the width and height get increased. I want the width and height to be specified so if the code is too long it just adds a scrollbar.

This is how big i want the codebox to be: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVopN.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post-header">SOME HEADER</div>
  
    <div class="post-content">
  
      <p> <pre><code class="language-js">
        
      </code></pre>
        <p>
        
  
    <img class="image-content">
    <div class="post-content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CSS property to your code box

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: i added `pre { overflow: scroll;}` and it didn't do anything. The codebox still covers the entire page 
This is how it looks after actually adding the full code that i want to in the codebox: [pic](https://imgur.com/a/3ggp9tu)

Comment: You of course need to add width and height to the code box for it to work

Answer (score 0):

added`<div style="height:200px;width:800px;overflow:auto">` next to pre tag, that seems to have fixed the issue.